# Create two different tables using the same model

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create two tables using SqlAlchemy, identical to each other in terms of structure, but with different names.

The tables look like this (simplified example):

```
Base = declarative_base()    

class MyTable(Base, OperationsMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'the_table_name'

    colA = Column(BigInteger)
    colB = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True))


class MyTableSecondary(MyTable):
    pass
```

To give MyTableSecondary a different name, what I think I should change is `__tablename__` (or even `__table__.name` and `__table__.fullname`).

However, if I do so, I'll change the values for the base class as well, since all those are class attributes.

To go around this limitation, I could add a `returnSecondary` to the base class along these lines:

```
def returnSecondary(self, suffix):
    tableArgs = list(self.__table_args__)
    for a in tableArgs:
        a.name += suffix

    classname = self.__class__.__name__ + 'Secondary'
    class_ = type(classname,
                  tuple(self.__class__.__bases__),
                  {'__tablename__': self.__tablename__ + suffix,
                   '__table_args__': tuple(self.__table_args__)})

    return class_
```

However, when I call it, it raises a KeyError for the first column defined.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create mixin

```
class MyTableMixin(object):
    colA = Column(BigInteger)
    colB = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True))

class MyTable(MyTableMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'the_table_name'

class MyTableSecondary(MyTableMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'secondary_table'
```

see [this example](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName)

As the example shows, this also works in the case one table has a superset of the columns the other table has.
In that case, you just need to add new columns as usual:

```
class MyTableTertiary(MyTableMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tertiary_table'
    some_other_col = Column(Integer)
```

Comment: Simple and effective. You nailed it!